# How to uniq an array case insensitive

Tags: ruby, arrays, unique

As far as i know, the result of

```
["a", "A"].uniq
```

is

```
["a", "A"]
```

My question is:

How do I make ["a", "A"].uniq give me either ["a"] or ["A"]

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Just make the case consistent first.

e.g:

```
["a","A"].map{|i| i.downcase}.uniq
```

**Edit:** If as mikej suggests, the elements returned must be exactly the same as in the original array, then this will do that for you:

```
a.inject([]) { |result,h| result << h unless result.map{|i| i.downcase}.include?(h.downcase); result }
```

**Edit2** Solution which should satisfy mikej :-)

```
downcased = [] 
a.inject([]) { |result,h| 
        unless downcased.include?(h.downcase);
            result << h
            downcased << h.downcase
        end;
        result}
```

Comment: Whilst this would work for the example given if the list was something like ["Hello", "HELLO"] then ["Hello", "HELLO"].map { |i| i.downcase }.uniq would return ["hello"] which doesn't match either of the strings in the original list.

Comment: Edited solution is good except that it will build the downcased list using result.map{|i| i.downcase} multiple times (once for each element in the original list) so maybe execute that once as a separate statement and store in a temporary variable if the list is large.

Comment: @Eric C's solution is much simpler.

Answer (score 44):

There is another way you can do this. You can actually pass a block to `uniq` or `uniq!` that can be used to evaluate each element.

```
["A", "a"].uniq { |elem| elem.downcase }  #=>  ["A"]
```

or

```
["A", "a"].uniq { |elem| elem.upcase }  #=>  ["A"]
```

In this case though, everything will be case insensitive so it will always return the array `["A"]`

Comment: Great answer. Note that a slightly shorter variation is `["A", "a"].uniq(&:downcase)`.

Comment: This solution will prefer the first duplication, in this case ["A"] and not ["a"].

Answer (score 7):

you may build a mapping (Hash) between the case-normalized (e.g. downcased) values and the actual value and then take just the values from the hash:

```
["a", "b", "A", "C"]\
.inject(Hash.new){ |h,element| h[element.downcase] = element ; h }\
.values
```

selects the last occurrence of a given word (case insensitive):

```
["A", "b", "C"]
```

if you want the first occurrence:

```
["a", "b", "A", "C"]\
.inject(Hash.new){ |h,element| h[element.downcase] = element  unless h[element.downcase]  ; h }\
.values
```

Answer (score 5):

```
["a", "A"].map{|x| x.downcase}.uniq
=> ["a"]
```

or

```
["a", "A"].map{|x| x.upcase}.uniq
=> ["A"]
```

Answer (score 5):

If you are using ActiveSupport, you can use **uniq_by**.
It doesn't affect the case of the final output.

```
['A','a'].uniq_by(&:downcase) # => ['A']
```

Answer (score 2):

A bit more efficient and way is to make use of uniq keys in hashes, so check this:

```
["a", "A"].inject(Hash.new){ |hash,j| hash[j.upcase] = j; hash}.values
```

will return the last element, in this case

```
["A"]
```

whereas using   *||=*   as assign operator:

```
["a", "A"].inject(Hash.new){ |hash,j| hash[j.upcase] ||= j; hash}.values
```

will return first element, in this case

```
["a"]
```

especially for big Arrays this should be faster as we don't search the array each time using *include?*

cheers...

Answer (score 0):

A more general solution (though not the most efficient):

```
class EqualityWrapper
  attr_reader :obj

  def initialize(obj, eq, hash)
    @obj = obj
    @eq = eq
    @hash = hash
  end

  def ==(other)
    @eq[@obj, other.obj]
  end

  alias :eql? :==

  def hash
    @hash[@obj]
  end
end

class Array
  def uniq_by(eq, hash = lambda{|x| 0 })
    map {|x| EqualityWrapper.new(x, eq, hash) }.
    uniq.
    map {|x| x.obj }
  end

  def uniq_ci
    eq = lambda{|x, y| x.casecmp(y) == 0 }
    hash = lambda{|x| x.downcase.hash }
    uniq_by(eq, hash)
  end
end
```

The `uniq_by` method takes a lambda that checks the equality, and a lambda that returns a hash, and removes duplicate objects as defined by those data.

Implemented on top of that, the `uniq_ci` method removes string duplicates using case insensitive comparisons.